# Failing to connect to database

Tags: codeigniter

When I run my localhost, I get these errors

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond.
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 203
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciblog\application\models\Post_model.php Line: 4
>   Function: database
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciblog\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server
>   using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/ciblog/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 436

I already tried to change the hostname to "mysql.hostingprovider.com:3306" but still get the error:

database.php file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysql.hostingprovider.com:3306',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '123456',
    'database' => 'posts',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Post_model.php file

```
<?php
    class Post_model extends CI_Model{
        public function __construct(){
            $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_posts($slug = FALSE){
            if($slug === FALSE){
                $query = $this->db->get('posts');
                return $query->result_array();
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
            return $query->row_array();

        }
    }
```

post.php file

```
<?php
    class Posts extends CI_Controller{
        public function index (){           
            $data['title'] = 'Latest Posts';

            $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts();
            print_r($data['post']);

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
```

Comment: your database is on the same server or on another server..?

Comment: i assume your database on your hostingprovider isn't accessible from outside ... what do you expect ?

Comment: same server i think, how to check it?

Comment: try hostname : localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: yeah already done that, still same error

Answer (score 0):

Change hostname:

```
*$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
............*
```

Comment: same error, the default is localhost, then i search it says like i type